# How can I make Turkish special characters to display properly?

Tags: babel, turkish

The following turkish characters do not seem to appear properly: "ğ, ı, ş"

I am using Miktex and my text editor is TeXnicCenter 2.02 Stable.
When I try to typeset the code, the PDF file ends up with question marks "?" in the place of the turkish special characters.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \begin{document}
   Merhaba. benim adım Billy. Taniştığımıza memnum oldum.
  \end{document}
```

**Result**: "Merhaba. benim ad?m Billy. Tani?t???m?za memnum oldum."

Comment: Your document should work as it is. I can not help with miktex customisation as I use texlive but check that cm-super is installed. (a full set of type 1 versions of the default computer modern fonts)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default computer modern doesn't have these glyphs. Add `\usepackage{lmodern}` or `cm-super` to your preamble, or install `cm-unicode`.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `cm-super`?

Comment: Oh yes! Actually, I didn't install it, because it takes up toomuch space, so I tend to forget it. Thanks for pointing this oversight.

Comment: I have also learn to never forget to refresh the file name database whenever finishing new files installations.

Comment: You're right, and also ro run `updmap.exe` from the command line if you install type 1 fonts.